# When is my biennial flight review due?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-61

I logged into my flying club's online scheduling website today (May 19, 2015) and it was warning me that my [Flight Review](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biennial_flight_review) was about to expire (on May 31, 2015). My last flight review was on June 7, 2013.

According to [14 CFR 61.56 (c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.56), the look-back period runs from *(my emphasis added)*:

> ... the beginning of the 24th calendar month **before** the month in
>   which that pilot acts as pilot in command ...

So am I right in calculating that my last Flight Review is actually valid through June 30, 2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Your interpretation is the correct one. Several FAA legal interpretations cover the "calendar months" phrasing; the best I could find was [the Harvey interpretation from 2012](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2012/harvey-morrisonmahoney%20-%20(2012)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf):

> Based on the facts that you have presented, a biennial flight review accomplished on April 2, 2002, would not lapse until May 1, 2004.

Basically, your flight review is legal until the end of the month (ie, June, or August) it was completed in two years before. The same calendar logic applies to maintenance like the annual inspection.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the FAA is concerned, your Flight Review is valid.

You may be running into a case where flight clubs can and often do create their own, more stringent rules.
They can require a BFR *within* two years, so you don't get the extra fractional-month grace period.

They could even require some currency-demonstration every few months!
Their planes, their rules.